# How to use External Accessory Framework without having a protocol from the MFi program

Tags: ios, external-accessory, mfi

We are planning to build a external device that will connect to the iPhone through the lightning port. The device is already working when you conect it via USB to a Mac.

We know we have to apply to the MFi program but in the meantime, is there any way to use the current external device with a development account and just for testing porpuses, without having a protocol string yet. We will like to use it in a initial phase, mesure efficent and building everything for the future release when we are in the MFi program.

I know I can use the EADemo, but running this project won't show any device if we don't provide a protocol for the external device ( which we don't have because we haven't applied to the MFi yet ).

For the same reason, we can't set up the External Accessory Framework in a test project without having a protocol:

```
 Applications that support external accessories must be sure to configure their Info.plist file correctly. 
 Specifically, you must include the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key to declare the specific hardware protocols your application supports
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Apple:

> No.  But even if there were that wouldn’t help because the accessory needs to speak a specific protocol in order to communicate with the iOS device, and the details of that protocol are only available via MFi.
>
> Share and Enjoy